# ESLint: 8.35.0 Error: "prettier/react" has been merged into "prettier" in eslint-config-prettier 8.0.0

Tags: reactjs, eslint, prettier, react-scripts, eslint-config-airbnb

Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 8.35.0

```
 Error: Cannot read config file: /home/jenkins/workspace/ Error: "prettier/react" has been merged into "prettier" in eslint-config-prettier 8.0.0. See: https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#version-800-2021-02-21
Referenced from: /home/jenkins/workspace/.eslintrc.json
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jenkins/workspace/node_modules/eslint-config-prettier/react.js:1:7)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
at Object.module.exports [as default] (/home/jenkins/workspace/node_modules/import-fresh/index.js:32:59)
at loadJSConfigFile (/home/jenkins/workspace/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/dist/eslintrc.cjs:2562:47)
at loadConfigFile (/home/jenkins/workspace/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/dist/eslintrc.cjs:2646:20)
at ConfigArrayFactory._loadConfigData (/home/jenkins/workspace/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/dist/eslintrc.cjs:2963:42).
```

.eslintrc.js :

```
{
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "root": true,
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "requireConfigFile": false,
    "babelOptions": {
      "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"]
    },
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "modules": true
    }
  },
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "airbnb/hooks",
    "plugin:cypress/recommended",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    },
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "paths": [
          "src",
          "cypress"
        ],
        "extensions": [
          ".js",
          ".jsx",
          ".ts",
          ".tsx"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "react-hooks",
    "cypress",
    "json"
  ]}
```

package.json file :

```
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/eslint-parser": "7.19.1",
"@babel/preset-env": "7.20.2",
"@babel/preset-react": "7.18.6",
"allure-commandline": "^2.20.1",
"concurrently": "^7.6.0",
"cross-env": "^7.0.3",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "19.0.4",
"eslint-config-prettier": "8.6.0",
"eslint-config-react": "1.1.7",
"eslint-plugin-cypress": "2.12.1",
"eslint-plugin-import": "2.27.5",
"eslint-plugin-json": "3.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.7.1",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
"json-server": "^0.15.1",
"lint-staged": "8.1.1",
"package-json-merge": "0.0.1",
"prettier": "2.8.4"
},
"eslintConfig": {
"extends": [
"react-app",
"react-app/jest"
]
}
```

After upgrading react-scripts to v 5.0.1 it required upgrading eslint plugins and config packages already used after that started getting above mentioned Error message and it only fails on the Jenkins gate while it works as expected locally.

Comment: Have you tried to do what the error tells you to do? https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#version-800-2021-02-21

Comment: yes, but getting the same error message. tried like this "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "airbnb/hooks",
    "plugin:cypress/recommended",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],